# Getting list is unhashable when use apply on a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a `DataFrame` `df` that that has a list in each row, and I want to apply the `remove_stops` function to each row.

```
import pandas as pd
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop = stopwords.words('english')

def remove_stops(row):
    meaningful_words = [w for w in row if not w in stop]
    return meaningful_words

df.apply(remove_stops)
```

When I run the code, I get the following error

```
meaningful_words = [w for w in row if not w in stop]
TypeError: ("unhashable type: 'list'", 'occurred at index original')
```

After some research, I understood the error is being caused because lists are not mutable.

```
print(type(df))
print(type(df.iloc[0, 0]))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'list'>
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: what is `c` that you are using with `apply` ?

Comment: Thanks for fixing the `c` variable in your code. This probably still isn't enough for us to figure out what's wrong though. How do you construct your dataframe? The answer to your problem probably lies in the way your dataframe interacts with the function you are applying.

Comment: [w for w in row if not w in stop_words]    did you mean 'stop' instead of 'stop_words' here?

Answer (score 1):

After explicitly using the name of the column I wanted to applycode as expected

```
df['original'].apply(remove_stops)
```

I was able to run the as intended. Thanks for the prompt replies.